# Laravel nova optional value 0 on belongsTo field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I am learning Laravel Nova for a project and I have a simple nested categories table:

```php
$table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
$table->dropPrimary('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->bigInteger('parent');
$table->primary(['name', 'parent', 'id']);
$table->timestamps();
```

I have a model for Category with:

```php
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'id', 'parent');
}
```

And I have a resource for Category in Nova with:

```php
BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', 'App\Nova\Category')
```

What I am trying to do is to have an option of selecting 0 (for top category with no parent) or choosing from existing categories.

Answer (score 3):

Add `->nullable()` to your Nova Field and it should work

```
BelongsTo::make('Parent', 'parent', 'App\Nova\Category')->nullable()
```

https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/89

Comment: Yep, this will work for his requirement.